# How to select the last level li in a multiple recursive structure having unknown number of inner nodes?

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-selectors

I need to select the last level of child element in the structure shown in snippet.
It's great if we can achieve this using css, but if it's not possible the jquery will be ok.

**Note: I can't change the HTML structure or add class in it.**

```css
ul li:last-child {
        color: #ff0000;
    }

    li {
        color: #000000;
    }
```

```html
<ul class="root">
   <li>no</li>
   <li>no</li>
   <li>yes</li>
</ul>
<ul class="root">
   <li>no</li>
   <li>no</li>
   <li>
      <ul>
         <li>no</li>
         <li>
            yes
            <ul>
               <li>no</li>
               <li>
                  yes
                  <ul>
                     <li>no</li>
                     <li>
                        yes
                        <ul>
                           <li>no</li>
                           <li>
                              yes
                              <ul>
                                 <li>no</li>
                                 <li>The last one, Only this need to be red!</li>
                              </ul>
                           </li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure since the depth is variable there's no pure CSS way to do this

Comment: can we add a class using jquery in the last level element?

Comment: Yup, that's doable

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-of-type This should be helpful to build a good selector

Comment: What if you have a tree with several branches going deep until some "leaf"? Should all of the leaves be targets?

Comment: No, only the last one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use JS until [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) is supported.

Here is one way to get the deepest `<li>` and add a class to it:

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll("li");

items[items.length - 1].classList.add("last");
```

```css
.last {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="root">
   <li>no</li>
   <li>no</li>
   <li>yes</li>
</ul>
<ul class="root">
   <li>no</li>
   <li>no</li>
   <li>
      <ul>
         <li>no</li>
         <li>
            yes
            <ul>
               <li>no</li>
               <li>
                  yes
                  <ul>
                     <li>no</li>
                     <li>
                        yes
                        <ul>
                           <li>no</li>
                           <li>
                              yes
                              <ul>
                                 <li>no</li>
                                 <li>The last one, Only this need to be red!</li>
                              </ul>
                           </li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```